# Understanding the use of gearman with memcached as persistent storage

Tags: php, mysql

I have configured Gearman on my Centos environment with both client and workers running on the same machine. It runs fine.

I am trying to use gearman with memcached persistent storage. I have compiled and installed gearman with libmemcached. So, I just start my memcached service and then run

```
gearmand 
PARAMS="-q
libmemcached
--libmemcached-servers=127.0.0.1:11211"
```

I now launch new jobs without any workers, I can see the queued up job on the [Gearman ui](https://github.com/gaspaio/gearmanui)

I now try to check the jobs by telnetting into memcached and I canot find anything.
I then stopped memcached service and then run

```
gearmand 
PARAMS="-q
libmemcached
--libmemcached-servers=127.0.0.1:11211"
```

It still runs fine, without any errors in the logs. I can still have clients and workers running. I am failing to understand if gearman is using memcached at all.

We have a lot of video encoding jobs to do. My ultimate aim is to have memcached on AWS, and then have my queue stored up there. Is that a good idea? And am I approaching this correctly?

## EDIT

As suggested in the answer, I changed the foreground jobs to background jobs and also tried to use mysql as the gearman queue. I did the following:

I have built gearman with libmysql.

```
 * CPP Flags:                  -fvisibility=hidden
   * LIBS:
   * LDFLAGS Flags:
   * Assertions enabled:        no
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * Building with libsqlite3   no
   * Building with libdrizzle   yes
   * Building with libmemcached yes
   * Building with libpq        no
   * Building with tokyocabinet no
   * Building with libmysql     yes
```

Inside my gearmand.conf file, I added the following, referring to other documentation:

```
PARAMS="--queue-type=mysql \
--mysql-host=localhost \
--mysql-port=3306 \
--mysql-user=root \
--mysql-db=deliver \
--mysql-table=gearman"
```

I can connect to my local mysql with root and there is a db called "deliver". When I run the gearmand server, and add new jobs and workers, I don't see table "gearman" created.

The processes seem to to run just fine. I have tried the verbose mode of logging and checking gearmand.log file, but there is nothing related to mysql. Where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to note about persistent queues in gearman. First, persistent queues are only used for background jobs. This means if the job has an attached client (i.e. it blocks), the persistent queue won't be used at all (*so if you were testing this on a typical hello-world/reverse-string example directly you won't see anything in the queue*).

From the [gearman manual](http://gearman.org/manual/job_server/#persistent_queues) (*referenced above*).

> The persistent queue is **only enabled for background jobs** because foreground jobs have an attached client. If a job server goes away, the client can detect this and restart the foreground job somewhere else (or report an error back to the original caller). Background jobs on the other hand have no attached client and are simply expected to be run when submitted.

Second, gearman keeps an in-memory queue natively, but callbacks are used to forward/remove jobs from the persistent queue as needed (in case the job server goes down), so there is the possibility the job was completed before you could fetch anything from the memcached server?

You could test this more concretely by running a test job with say `sleep(100)` or something similar and it's possible you might be able to check memcached that way while the job is still running.

Also note that there are some known bugs in gearmand with libmemcached que-type on some distros like Debian (at least that I know of) where it has some race conditions. You might want to try running gearmand with `--verbose DEBUG` for those.